# Ionic Grid - Two buttons with different content but with the same size, side by side

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

I have an element which is a header with two buttons. I have the buttons organized in a `ion-grid`, where the two buttons are **side by side with the same size and centered in the column**. This way the size is perfect for mobiles, but the buttons are too big when using a browser:

```
<ion-header>
    <ion-toolbar>       
        <ion-grid>
            <ion-row>
                <ion-col size="6" class="ion-text-center">
                    <ion-button style="width: 75%;">Menu</ion-button>
                </ion-col>
                <ion-col size="6" class="ion-text-center">
                    <ion-button style="width: 75%;">Abcdefghijklmn</ion-button>
                </ion-col>
            </ion-row>
        </ion-grid>
    </ion-toolbar>
    <style>html, body { margin: 0; }</style>
</ion-header>
```

I tried to change the `min-width` and `max-width`, but when it gets perfect for browser screen size it gets too small for mobile and the button became smaller then the text inside.

As suggested [here](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/making-buttons-side-by-side/162278/11?u=leonardofmed), I tried to apply `expand="full"`, `class="ion-text-wrap"` and set a `max-width` to the button, but it loses its center property defined by `class="ion-text-center"` on `ion-col`. I then added `style="text-align: center"` to maintain the center property in `ion-col` tag, but does not make difference`.

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-4-angular-8-start-template-skeqqi?file=src/app/tab1/tab1.page.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make responsive grid like this. (You may adjust grid size for your use case)

Ref : https://ionicframework.com/docs/layout/grid#grid-size

```html
<ion-grid>
    <ion-row>
        <ion-col size-sm="6" size="6" class="ion-text-center">
            <ion-button expand="full" class="ion-text-wrap min-max-width">Menu</ion-button>
        </ion-col>

        <ion-col size-sm="6" size="6" class="ion-text-center">
            <ion-button expand="full" class="ion-text-wrap min-max-width">Abcdefghijklmn</ion-button>
        </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
</ion-grid>

<style>
    .min-max-width {
        max-width: 200px;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: I thought of doing this way by adding empty columns, but I don't think it's visually pleasing because the buttons seem to be "pulled" to the middle, even if I change the size of the columns.

Comment: using grid view to manage UI is good way, but if you don't want this then you can also manage this by using media query css for large and small screen

Comment: Also please explain your case once more

Comment: Of course, I will explain again, I need the two buttons to be side by side, the same size and centered in their own column, considering that they are two columns, one on the left of the screen and one on the right. By the method you gave me, although the buttons are the same size, they don't seem to be centered when the screen is expanded (browser size), but rather with that "pull" look to the center. If it is still unclear, please let me know. [Latest Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-4-angular-8-start-template-skeqqi?file=src/app/tab1/tab1.page.html)